# Problem with Keystone and Openstack. The request you have made requires authentication. (HTTP 401)

Tags: linux, debian, auth, log, autenticacion

openstack project create --domain default --description "Service Project" service
The request you have made requires authentication. (HTTP 401) (Request-ID: req-e48b1efa-5790-488f-8374-e3a385bffc7e)
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.